# Mouse Acceleration in Manjaro 18.0.1

Tags: linux, xorg, manjaro

Hi the configuration of Mouse Acceleration is a very weird Manjaro Cinnamon edition. Maybe someone can help me to understand how it works.

I tried to change the setting via gue in mouse setting, it seems like the system just ignores the setting there so that panel is simply useless.

I have installed xinput. Tried setting `xinput --set-prop 16 'libinput Accel Speed' -0.8` It did not work initially.

So then I started reading the article [Mouse Acceleration - wiki.archliniux.org](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Mouse_acceleration) tried to create `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/50-mouse-deceleration.conf` system simply ignored it. 
Then erased `50-mouse-deceleration.conf` and created new one `99-libinput-custom-config.conf` which I found here [forum.manjaro.org](https://forum.manjaro.org/t/disabling-mouse-acceleration-for-gamers/63489/19), it changed something but `xinput list-props 16` still showed acceleration at 0, if I changed it using this command `xinput --set-prop 16 'libinput Accel Speed' -0.8` it substantially reduce the mouse speed, which I was really happy about. 
But now the problem is that I can't make the change permanent. I tried adding this command in `~/.xinitrc` at the end with `exec` and without. But after restart the `libinput Accel Speed` remains at 0.

xset doesn't seem to work at all. Can you please help.

Answer (score 0):

I have moved to Arch Linux since the posted this question a long time ago. I hope this will help those of you who are struggling with this problem. 
There was some errors in my 99-libinput-custom-config.conf which reminds me the most of the time when something doesn't work its human factor, currently, it looks like so and it works for me in Arch I think it should be relevant for Manjaro as well:

```
Section "InputClass"
  Identifier "My Mouse"
  MatchIsPointer "yes"
  # MatchVendor "Logitech, Inc."
  # MatchProduct "G9x Laser Mouse"
  Option "AccelSpeed" "-1"
EndSection
```

If you type `xinput` you should get a list something among these lines

```
⎡ Virtual core pointer                          id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Corsair Corsair K30A Gaming Keyboard      id=13   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Logitech G9x Laser Mouse                  id=9    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Logitech G9x Laser Mouse Consumer Control id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                         id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Logitech G9x Laser Mouse Keyboard         id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Corsair Corsair K30A Gaming Keyboard      id=16   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ HD Pro Webcam C920                        id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Corsair Corsair K30A Gaming Keyboard      id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Corsair Corsair K30A Gaming Keyboard      id=14   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Logitech G9x Laser Mouse Consumer Control id=15   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

you should look at the section `Virtual core pointer` to the row with your pointer device name and type like in my case `xinput list-props 9` where 9 is id. This should generate a list like so

```
Device 'Logitech G9x Laser Mouse':
        Device Enabled (152):   1
        Coordinate Transformation Matrix (154): 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000
        libinput Natural Scrolling Enabled (286):       0
        libinput Natural Scrolling Enabled Default (287):       0
        libinput Scroll Methods Available (288):        0, 0, 1
        libinput Scroll Method Enabled (289):   0, 0, 0
        libinput Scroll Method Enabled Default (290):   0, 0, 0
        libinput Button Scrolling Button (291): 2
        libinput Button Scrolling Button Default (292): 2
        libinput Middle Emulation Enabled (293):        0
        libinput Middle Emulation Enabled Default (294):        0
        libinput Accel Speed (295):     -1.000000
        libinput Accel Speed Default (296):     0.000000
        libinput Accel Profiles Available (297):        1, 1
        libinput Accel Profile Enabled (298):   1, 0
        libinput Accel Profile Enabled Default (299):   1, 0
        libinput Left Handed Enabled (300):     0
        libinput Left Handed Enabled Default (301):     0
        libinput Send Events Modes Available (271):     1, 0
        libinput Send Events Mode Enabled (272):        0, 0
        libinput Send Events Mode Enabled Default (273):        0, 0
        Device Node (274):      "/dev/input/event21"
        Device Product ID (275):        1133, 49254
        libinput Drag Lock Buttons (302):       <no items>
        libinput Horizontal Scroll Enabled (303):
```

If you look at my results at line that looks like so `libinput Accel Speed (295):     -1.000000` you will start noticing the similarities with my custom config where I do the following `Option "AccelSpeed" "-1"`. This [post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/58117/determine-xinput-device-manufacturer-and-model) should help you to identify MatchVendor and MatchProduct if you need it. 
Hope this helps.